# Is there a way to catch script manual termination?

Tags: python, exit

I have a python script that launches a subprocess which then opens a python terminal window that displays its running logs/status output.

If the user closes the window, the process terminates - this is desirable. However, I cannot figure out a way to "catch" and log if the user manually terminates the script (closes window).

I have tried putting my main() in a try/except block but it seems that no exceptions are being raised (like a KeyboardInterrupt).

Also tried atexit package - but this seems only to take into effect at normal script termination.

Is there a way to log/print to file when a user terminates a script mid run?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  I suspect that closing the window kills the Python process with a signal.  If so, then you could set up a signal handler (see the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)).  Which operating system is this?

Comment: My script is running on Windows 10. Signal handling... will check it out - seems a bit of an advanced topic. Thank you